# Python PyQt Program Structure

Tags: python, class, pyqt

I am planing to create a program that will do the following:

- Ask the username/password
- Depending on the username at the login page, user will be presented with 2 different GUIs. That is, if user name is in my administrator list, the user will be presented with administration page. If the user name is in normal user list, the user will be presented with other relevant page.
- For both `administrator` and `user` interfaces, there will be a toolbar with several tool buttons which will create a new dialog window.

Currently the program structure i have is a single class like this:

```
class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def__init__(self,parent=None):
        ------

    def ShowLoginPage(self):
        #this is the code to create login page GUI
        ---- 
        ----
        button.clicked.connect(self.Process_login) # Submit button for username/password

    def ShowAdminPage(self):
        #this is the code to create admin page GUI
        ----
        ----

    def ShowUserPage(self):
        #this is the code to create user page GUI
        ----
        ----

    def Process_login(self):
        #this is the code to check if username is admin or user
        if username in username_list:
             self.ShowUserPage()
        elif username in adminname_list:
             self.ShowAdminPage()
```

Both `ShowAdminPage` and `ShowUserPage` methods are actually just creating 2 different `Central Widgets` and setting them.

My questions are.

1. Is the above structure can be improved? Personally, i don't really think it's a good idea to put everything in a single class like this. But i am a beginner and i have no idea what kind of alternate way i can use to create it.
2. What are some good practice to follow when building a multipage GUI program like this?

Comment: This question appears to be better suited for http://codereview.stackexchange.com


Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is good for this functionality, but don't create centralWidgets for admin and normal user, just use `QStackedWidget`. You can design QStackedWidget in QtDesigner and display the appropriate Widget from `QStackedWidget` depending upon which user is logged in and when user switch from admin to normal user and from normal to admin user, just switch the widgets in the `QStackedWidget`.

Answer (score 0):

I make functions like `ShowLoginPage(self)` in other module (as static functions) and `self` named as `mainwindow`. Such, I have many module differ by functionality.